# Pass/loop 2 register output lines (has list of values each) to next task in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I'm trying to pass 2 register list values to a task. but when I pass both the list , it is not looping to the register values but its just passing the complete array of list.

**data (ls -ld)**

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root           root                 4096 Jun  4  2019 dir_1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root           root                 4096 Jun  4  2019 dir_2
drwxr-xr-x  2 ram            ram                  4096 Jun  4  2019 dir_3
drwxr-xr-x  2 mike           mike                 4096 Jun  4  2019 dir_4
```

**Code**

```
- name: Get Owners
  become: false
  shell: ls -ld  | awk '{print $3}'
  args:
    chdir: /data
  register: owner

- name: Get foldernames
  become: false
  shell: ls -ld | awk '{print  $9}'
  args:
    chdir: /data
  register: foldername

- name: check if its able to loop.
  debug:
    msg: "{{item.a}}:{{item.b}}"
  loop:
    - { a: "{{ owner.stdout_lines }}", b: "{{ foldername.stdout_lines }}" }
```

**output**

```
Instead of having the output looped its copying the whole (stdout_lines) list in array 

"msg": "[u'root', u'root', u'ram', u'mike']:[u'dir_1', u'dir_2', u'dir_3', u'dir_4']
```

How can I get the data (owner and foldername) looped and passed to the msg one by one in a sequence (and right owner to folername).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"How can I get the data (owner and foldername) looped and passed to the msg one by one in a sequence (and right owner to folername)."*

A: There are more options.

1) Use [zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together). For example

```
- name: debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0 }} - {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ owner.stdout_lines|zip(foldername.stdout_lines)|list }}"
```

2) It's possible to [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) the directories and [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) registered *result* in the *loop*. For example

```
    - find:
        path: data
        file_type: directory
      register: result

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} - {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files|json_query('[].[pw_name, path]') }}"
```